# HtmlAgility pack error on a sitecore CMS website

Tags: sitecore, html-agility-pack

I have rercently installed HtmlAgility pack on a website that runs on Sitecore CMS.

everysince I have been getting an error on my app start that says "Field not found: 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.ElementsFlags'."

[image]

I have checked the the code of Sitecore.kernal dll using a decompiler and below is the screenshot of the code that throws this error. Does anyone know how to fix this ?

[image]

Comment: What verison of Sitecore is used? What version of HtmlAgilityPack you have?

Comment: You may be able to use Binding Redirects in your web.config, but will depend on which version of HAP you're are switching between and compatibility.

Comment: @SitecoreClimber I am using Sitecore 6.5. HtmlAgilityPack -Version 1.4.6.0

Comment: Thank you.  sitecore is using HtmlAgilitypack 1.4.0 I am using HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.6.  I have updated the solution to use HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.0 and that solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore by default uses `HtmlAgilityPack` dll. In my version it uses `1.4.6.0` version of `HtmlAgilityPack`.

[image: html agility pack sitecore]

Most probably you installed a version of `HtmlAgilityPack` which is not compatible with Sitecore.

Try to check what is the version of `HtmlAgilityPack.dll` in your `bin` folder and change the reference to include `1.4.6.0` instead.

Comment: Thank you.  sitecore is using HtmlAgilitypack 1.4.0 I am using HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.6.  I have updated the solution to use HtmlAgilityPack 1.4.0 and that solved the problem